# What is the best single useState or multiple useState to optimize reactjs app performance?

Tags: reactjs

I want to optimize ReactJS app performance which is the best to use?

1-using an object:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState({ count: 4, theme: 'blue'});
```

2- Creating multiple React useState Hooks:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(4);
const [theme, setTheme] = useState('blue');
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

Comment: second way! 100%

Answer (score 2):

According to the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables):

> we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together

However, in terms of performance, according to a [benchmark](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2021/10/11/usestate-object-vs-multiple/) performed by Vladimir Klepov, useState with primatives is slightly better than object, perhaps due to the cost of object allocations. However,

> Note that the difference here is in sub-microsecond range (yes, MICROsecond, 1/1000th of a millisecond, or 1/16000th of a 60FPS frame), so any practical implications are laughable.

All in all, it is better to write your state hooks in a way that is more readable rather than focus on any premature optimizations since the difference is minimal. You'll probably be able to gain more performance by spending your time benchmarking to find slow performing components of your application and using memoization to prevent unnecessary re-renders.